# How can I get tools to accept TypeScript exhaustiveness checking without a lot of comments?

Tags: typescript, istanbul, typescript-eslint

I write a lot of code that uses exhaustiveness checking.

In the code below, the line with `_exhaustivenessCheck` will (intentionally) have a type error if someone adds to the `UnitOfTime` union. I like this style of programming, but when combined with code coverage and a strong linter it becomes a pain:

```
function waterFrequencyToMilliseconds(unitOfTime: UnitOfTime): number {
  switch (unitOfTime) {
    case 'days':
      return number * ONE_DAY;
    case 'weeks':
      return number * ONE_WEEK;
  }
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const _exhaustivenessCheck: never = unitOfTime;
}
```

I need to tell both istanbul and eslint to leave me alone when I am doing the right thing.

Is there a standard way to deal with this situation without having to add the "ignore" and "disable" comments or turn off the lint rules or code coverage entirely?

Comment: why do you need to explicitly do that? even without the `never` assignment the compiler will complain if someone adds a value - [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgS2AeQGYBUEFtoF4oDkAJgIYgDOBUAPoQO4QQDWlNhIEJATpQFC8BjAPZxywKMgByAUQD6AEQCCATSj4AjIJFiJM2QHVp0gNJqoAdl6oArnAHAEIqHRLAIXAGJcIAR2sQ7EHQhAFkEABtwhHIIYTgicgAKOAAuKDhrLAAjdwAaKFskNEwcNPgijGwIAEo0jOz3KABvXigocjokAQALKETClEqcaubWtqgBEhjCUgoCNJbx8e9gay44dKgAKl05JWUAbjG2gF9jianoAgZmSgXztpW1jY2dqTlDEyOls9PeE6AA)

Comment: @thedude I remember having to do something like this with earlier versions of TypeScript.

Comment: @thedude, in your example there is always an error: "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'."

Comment: @MaxHeiber correct, that's the error that shows up if you don't exhaustively check all possibilities. If you cover all the cases, the error goes away. So if someone adds something to the union without adding code to handle it, the error will reappear

Comment: @MaxHeiber that's because I added a value that is not handled by the switch. If I remove it, the error goes away [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgS2AeQGYBUEFtoF4oDkAJgIYgDOBUAPoQO4QQDWlUAUGwMYD2c5wUZADkAogH0AIgEEAmlHwBGLr36DRYgOoiRAaXlQA7G1QBXOJ2AJeUOiWAQATgDEHEAI4mI5kOm4BZBAAbQIRyCB44InIACjgALig4EywAI0cAGigzJDRMHAT4HIxsCABKBKTUxygAbzYoKHI6JE4ACyho7JRinFLa+oaoThIwwlIKAgS6wcHXYBMHOESoACo1cWkZAG4BhoBfXaGR6AIGZkopw4a5haWlteFxLV0dmYP9tj2gA)

Comment: @thedude thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For TypeScript going back to at least TS 3.1.6, (the earliest version I can easily test), you do not need to add an explicit exhaustiveness check like

```
const _exhaustivenessCheck: never = unitOfTime;
```

for final `switch` statements in a function if they are seen as exhaustive by the compiler.  That is, there is no error here:

```
function waterFrequencyToMilliseconds(number: number, unitOfTime: UnitOfTime): number {
  switch (unitOfTime) {
    case 'days': {
      return number * ONE_DAY;
    }
    case 'weeks': {
      return number * ONE_WEEK;
    }
  }
}
```

whereas if your `switch` statement isn't exhaustive you'll get an error:

```
function oopsWaterFrequencyToMillis(number: number, unitOfTime: UnitOfTime): number { 
// error! function lacks ending return statement --------------------------> ~~~~~~
  switch (unitOfTime) {
    case 'days': {
      return number * ONE_DAY;
    }
  }
}
```

So for the specific example code listed here, you should just remove your exhaustiveness check.

---

Additionally, since TypeScript 3.7, TypeScript has [better support for detecting unreachability via control-flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions) so that you shouldn't need to explicitly `throw` or `return` in any situation where the compiler sees that you are in an unreachable part of the code, such as after an exhaustive `switch` statement.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695#issuecomment-531788740) in the pull request implementing this for more information.

And so not only isn't there a *need* for an explicit exhaustiveness check, such a check will actually produce an unreachability warning in TS3.7+:

```
function explicitExhaustiveCheck(number: number, unitOfTime: UnitOfTime): number {
  switch (unitOfTime) {
    case 'days': {
      return number * ONE_DAY;
    }
    case 'weeks': {
      return number * ONE_WEEK;
    }
  }
  const _exhaustivenessCheck: never = unitOfTime; // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  //unreachable code detected.
}
```

So you should definitely remove that check.

---

If you need to support older versions of TS and you have example code that shows a need for an explicit exhaustiveness check, you might want to replace the variable declaration with an explicit `return` statement like `return assertNever(unitOfTime)` where `assertNever()` only accepts `never` arguments.  This could possibly make your linters happy.  But for now, without a reproducible example of such an issue, I think the question as asked is as answered as I can make it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgS2AeQGYBUEFtoF4oDkAJgIYgDOBUAPoQO4QQDWlAUAMYD2c5wUyAOQCiAfQAiAQQCaUfAEYADEqgAqKADYFqjVrUAmACwduvfsJEB1IUIDSsqAHZtg0ZKkBuVq1QBXOO2AEbig6EmAIACcAMQiIAEcfCH8QdE4AWQQAG0yEcgguOCJyAAo4HywAI0iALigyysiAGig-JDRMHFr4NoxsCABKWvqqiKgAb1YoKHI6JHYACyhi1pRenH7xyamodhI8wlIKAlqJ7e3Y4B8IuDrykedzN08zgF8tqd39ggZmShP384QS7XW4NUZqFyWaw2Z7bN5TN5vbx+AJBG6cThgcgWMKRGLxRLJVIZbK5Up3GqgkbNFbtPpdRCrDoDIYU0ZjKCsAD0XKgkQinAiAEIoL5-IFgpkSOwWHzCgg4ABzKAXK43Xi4nBwPgAWj1+oNhqNhoAfFAAH6Wq1bGZzRbLRl09abM6faDEMh-F1nFVAtVUyIPVzSWEIraIrxi1HBCAADzAOXYSCEsfmJB8vAQADcIABheb5JjksGssE0x1rCAMnrMwYB9k22bABZLWmVjanbZug6e47es6qkHDQMQx4hgHwrt7d0-Fh9zsDv1DtlBqG2UNQSeTgqmERxtMZwI5uAQcjkfOFoYQHOjfBt5nuKA8vkRAXCrY8q1f78-39--9fh+XJ+LE0pphUmTQFwRDQDB4QBBARAAHSsEiQA)

Comment: I agree I should remove the `_exhaustivenessCheck` line, but then the error message gets way worse: `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`With the `_exhaustivenessCheck` thing TS explains exactly what is missing. Is there a way to get a nice error message?